# How can I get an accurate count of rows within a PostgresSQL table based upon a record type?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

How can I get an accurate count of subscribers that are "active" and subscribers that are "inactive/suspended"?

I tried following the documentation, but it's a bit vague on how to match records within a pg_class:

```
ANALYZE subscribers; 
SELECT reltuples AS estimate 
FROM   pg_class 
WHERE relname = 'subscribers' 
(and where status = 'active' / where status= 'inactive' or status='suspended')
```

The above query returns 24, when I want it to return:

```
estimate (active): 12
estimate (inactive/suspended): 12
```

**Update**: It looks like the below query works, but may be a resource intensive. Is there a better alternative to:

```
SELECT count(*) AS active
FROM   subscribers
WHERE  status = 'active';

SELECT count(*) AS inactive
FROM   subscribers
WHERE  status = 'inactive'
OR     status = 'suspended';
```

**Table Example**:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS subscribers;

CREATE TABLE subscribers (
  id VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1mc(),
  key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  status VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'inactive',
  email VARCHAR,
  subscriber VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR,
  phone VARCHAR,
  plan VARCHAR,
  startDate TEXT DEFAULT TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'Mon DD, YYYY'),
  endDate TEXT,
  amount DECIMAL(12,2),
  isGod BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);

INSERT INTO subscribers (status, email, subscriber, password, phone, plan, endDate, amount)
  VALUES
  ('active', 'admin@admin.com', 'Admin', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'squatters@gmail.com', 'Sherry Waters', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'bob-eh@sap.com', 'Bob Aronssen', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'shani.smith@hotmail.com', 'Shaniqua Smith', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'tanyaballschin@gmail.com', 'Tanya Ballschin', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'lukeskywalker@rebelforce.com', 'Siemen Walker', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'jTank@aol.com', 'Jenny Tanks', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'amberLamps@yahoo.com', 'Amber Lalampas', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'kylebTeegue@gmail.com', 'Kyle Teegue', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'snakePiliskin@gmail.com', 'Gary Pilkinson', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'yasminRod@hotmail.com', 'Yasmin Rodrigues', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('active', 'adaDamn@photonmail.com', 'Adam Johnson', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', null, 29.99),
  ('inactive', 'carlsagan42@yahoo.com', 'Carl Sagan', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 3, 2018', 29.99),
  ('inactive', 'seamark@outlook.com', 'Mark Canelo', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 12, 2018', 29.99),
  ('suspended', 'axxll@manjaro.com', 'Axle Root', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 16, 2018', 29.99),
  ('inactive', 'vicksAdam@sap.com', 'Adamn Vicks', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 17, 2018', 29.99),
  ('inactive', 'wallyworld@manjaro.com', 'Wes Walls', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 17, 2018', 29.99),
  ('suspended', 'kellyUll@gmail.com', 'Kelly Ullman', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 17, 2018', 29.99),
  ('inactive', 'oatesA@aol.com', 'Adam Oates', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 17, 2018', 29.99),
  ('suspended', 'scottParker@jaro.com', 'Scott Parker', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 21, 2018', 29.99),
  ('suspended', 'asmLossenger@mancusco.com', 'Emily Loz', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 22, 2018', 29.99),
  ('inactive', 'pparks@akins.com', 'Parker Posey', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 29, 2018', 29.99),
  ('suspended', 'aleashtrails@kilmas.com', 'Alisha Tallis', 'password', '(555) 555-555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 29, 2018', 29.99),
  ('suspended', '88Damon@photonmail.com', 'Damien Smith', 'password', '(555) 555-5555', 'Carlotta Prime', 'Jan 29, 2018', 29.99);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: having a uuid **and** a serial seems overkill.

Comment: This "key" is required and used by a React UI library. If the key is missing from the record, it'll complain. Otherwise, I would just have the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT count(*) filter (where status = 'active') AS active, 
       count(*) filter (where status in ('inactive', 'suspended')) as inactive
FROM subscribers
```

Comment: Bench marked all suggestions and this one appears to be the quickest query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select case when status = 'active'
         then 'estimate (active):'
         else 'estimate (inactive/suspended):'
       end S,
       count(*)
  from subscribers group by S;


               s                | count 
--------------------------------+-------
 estimate (active):             |    12
 estimate (inactive/suspended): |    12
(2 rows)
```

Or something that approaches your layout more closely:

```
     select case when status = 'active'
             then 'estimate (active): '
             else 'estimate (inactive/suspended): '
           end ||
           count(*) estimatum
      from (select case when status = 'active'
                     then status else 'X' end status
              from subscribers) as S
      group by  status;

             estimatum         
-----------------------------------
 estimate (active): 12
 estimate (inactive/suspended): 12
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"…the below query works, but may be a resource intensive. Is there a better alternative…"*

I think you mean you want to avoid a full scan of the table. It is possible to extract an estimate from the planner (credit [to Michael Fuhr](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate)):

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION count_estimate(query text) RETURNS INTEGER AS
> $func$
> DECLARE
>     rec   record;
>     ROWS  INTEGER;
> BEGIN
>     FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ' || query LOOP
>         ROWS := SUBSTRING(rec."QUERY PLAN" FROM ' rows=([[:digit:]]+)');
>         EXIT WHEN ROWS IS NOT NULL;
>     END LOOP;
>
>     RETURN ROWS;
> END
> $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
> select count_estimate($$select * from subscribers where status='active'$$);
> ```
>
> ```
> | count_estimate |
> | -------------: |
> |             12 |
> ```

> ```
> select count_estimate($$select * from subscribers where status='inactive' or status='suspended'$$);
> ```
>
> ```
> | count_estimate |
> | -------------: |
> |             10 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=fbea0389d686b77fff951912430dc753)*

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
SELECT count(*), status FROM subscribers GROUP BY status;
```

this query will give you counts for active, inactive and suspended status.

> Result will be status, status_count format

As long as you don't have any other status, this query is ok.